# Apache POI JAR files compatibility issue

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am creating a web application project which has a feature to upload an Excel file and then the data from that Excel file will be saved into the database (MySQL). In the back-end (Java) to parse the Excel file, Apache POI JAR files are used. I have placed the JAR files in my `WEB-INF/lib` folder which are:

- poi-5.2.5
- poi-ooxml-5.2.5
- poi-ooxml-schemas-4.1.2

Because of the version conflict between the `poi-ooxml-schemas-4.1.2` and the other two JAR files, I get an error on the console:

```
Jan 16, 2024 1:57:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [UploadServlet] in context with path [/Teachersdairy] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Factory
```

I can't find the more recent version for `poi-ooxml-schemas-4.1.2` than this. If there is another JAR file of `poi-ooxml-schemas` which is capable with the POI 5.2.5 version then please let me know or any other versions of `poi` and `poi-ooxml` which are capable with `poi-ooxml-schemas-4.1.2`.

I tried to find the latest version of `poi-ooxml-schemas-4.1.2`. Now I want to know which versions of all three JAR files are compatible with each other.

Comment: As listed in the 5.0.0 [changelog](https://poi.apache.org/changes.html): _"Change artifact names of poi-/ooxml-schemas to poi-ooxml-lite/full"_

Comment: As an aside, I highly recommend switching to using Maven or Gradle instead of managing your dependencies manually.

Answer (score 4):

Since Apache POI 5.0.0, the `poi-ooxml-schemas` dependency has been replaced with `poi-ooxml-lite` or `poi-ooxml-full`. See the [changelog](https://poi.apache.org/changes.html) for version 5.0.0:

> Change artifact names of poi-/ooxml-schemas to poi-ooxml-lite/full

In other words, replace `poi-ooxml-schemas` with `poi-ooxml-lite` (or if you need the extra features, `poi-ooxml-full`) with the exact same version as your main POI dependencies.

As I also said in the comment, part of this could have been prevented by using Maven or Gradle to manage your dependencies, as the `poi-ooxml` 4.1.2 and older Maven dependency automatically pulled in `poi-ooxml-schemas`, and since 5.0.0 it pulls in `poi-ooxml-lite`. So, if you had used either Maven or Gradle to manage your dependencies (and not explicitly depended on `poi-ooxml-schemas`), the upgrade would have happened automatically.